# How is constant represented?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I would like to know if a variable is declared as volatile constant, can it be changed using i/o or any peripherals?
for example:
volatile const int input = 0;
Also such a variable can be stored where in the memory?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: @pranitkothari No, it's just way too broad.

Answer (score 5):

When a variable is defined as `const`, the system takes it as read-only variable. A variable whose value should not be modified. However, by defining a variable as `volatile` the programmer is asking the compiler to avoid compiler optimization.

Lets take an example:
`volatile const int flag = 0;`

It says `flag` is a variable whose value shouldn't be modified and asking the compiler to avoid compiler optimization, meaning, suggesting the compiler that the value of flag can be changed during operation by some other system process.

A very good example is the PSW or CPSR (Program Status Word) register in the processor. It is read-only to the user (example of `const`) and can only be modified by the system whenever an arithmetic or logical operation is done by the system (example of `volatile`).

I hope it helps.

Comment: +1 yes this does. "suggesting the compiler that the value of flag can be changed during operation by some other system process" is particularly good.

Comment: @AhmedNour Please edit your question and be more specific and add details to narrow the answer set so that one can provide the best answer. It is not a good practice to ask such a broad question where you will have multiple good answers and answers that may deviate from actual requirement. **Just a suggestion as you are new to SO.**

Answer (score 2):

It's purely down to the compiler, subject to any constraints that the relevant standard introduces. Given that you can take an address of a constant and assign that to a pointer, you could conject that the constant occupies memory in that instance.

But this doesn't really hint on how constants are stored in memory. A compiler could optimise them out altogether if there are no side effects in doing so. Alternatively, `const char* foobar = "foobar"` and `const char* bar = "bar"` may not even occupy disjoint locations: attempting to modify either (formally *undefined behaviour*) would be disastrous. Using `volatile` does suppress some optimisations but the exact behaviour is still compiler-dependent.